# type narrowing with custom react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a custom component to show a component conditionally.

```
interface Props {
  condition: boolean;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function If(props: Props) {
  if (props.condition) {
    return props.children;
  }

  return null;
}
```

when I use this component, thought I made and used a validate function using `is` keyword, type cannot be narrowed.

```
interface Alert {
  message: {
    title: string;
    content: string;
  }
}

interface P {
  alert?: Alert;
}

function Test(props: P) {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
      <If condition={hasAlert(props.alert)}>
        <div>
          <span>{props.alert.message.title}</span> // here I got an error
        </div>
      </If>
    </div>
  );
}

function hasAlert(alert?: Alert): alert is Alert {
  return !isEmpty(alert);
}
```

how can I make this `If` component support type narrowing?

I've tried make a validate function(as mentioned above), passing a callback instead of boolean variable 'condition'. but neither don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error because the interface `P` indicates that the property `alert` might not exist (due to the `?` operator) or it is going to be of type `Alert`. Therefore, you have to check if the property has been defined.

Just use the `?.` operator to avoid the error, that way if you don’t provide the `alert` property, react is not going to try to access `undefined` and throw an error

```
<span>{props.alert?.message.title}</span>
```

Or you could also conditionally render by narrowing the type.

```
{props.alert && <span>{props.alert.message.title}</span>}
```

Here we’re making sure that `props.alert` is not undefined, therefore Typescript will let you treat `props.alert` as an `Alert`.